# Command to insert lines before first match

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have file with the below info

```
testing
testing
testing
```

I want to insert a word(tested) before the first testing word using sed or any linux command

need to get output like

```
tested
testing
testing
testing
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For lines consisting of "testing" exactly:

```
sed '0,/^testing$/s/^testing$/tested\n&/' file
```

For lines containing "testing":

```
sed '0,/.*testing.*/s/.*testing.*/tested\n&/' file
```

For Lines Starting with "testing"

```
sed '0,/^testing.*/s/^testing.*/tested\n&/' file
```

For lines ending with "testing":

```
sed '0,/.*testing$/s/.*testing$/tested\n&/' file
```

To update the content of the file with the result add "-i", example:

```
sed -i '0,/testing/s/testing/tested\n&/' file
```

Answer (score 14):

To provide an `awk`-based alternative that is easier to understand:

```
awk '!found && /testing/ { print "tested"; found=1 } 1' file
```

- `found` is used to keep track of whether the first instance of `testing` has been found (variable `found`, as any Awk variable, defaults to `0`, i.e., `false` in a Boolean context).
- `/testing/` therefore matches the *first* line containing `testing`, and processes the associated block:

  - `{ print "tested"; found=1 }` prints the desired text and sets the flag that the first `testing` line has been found
- `1` is a common shorthand for `{ print }`, i.e., simply printing the current input line as is.

Answer (score 8):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/testing/{itested' -e ':a;n;ba}' file
```

Insert `tested` before the first match of `testing` and then use a loop to read/print the remainder of the file.

Or use the GNU specific:

```
sed '0,/testing/!b;//itested' file
```

Comment: `sed -e '0,/testing/itested'` will insert `tested` before _every_ line of the file, up to and including the matching line. To get the required behavior, I think you'd have to say `sed -e '0,/testing/{//itested' -e '}'`, which is significantly less pleasing. (The `//` is short for "match the same thing as the previous pattern". The second `-e` specifies the second line of the sed script, since the `i` command consumes the rest of the line.)

Comment: @smammy you are right, I am guilty of not using my own test data and relying on the OP. I will amend the second solution.

Comment: I like your revised GNU-specific solution a lot! I didn't think of negating the address range and branching to the next cycle. Saves you from having to use braces or multiple `-e` options which seems cleaner.

Comment: @smammy it depends on the way your mind works, some people prefer to think positively, but there are always at least two sides to any argument.

Answer (score 4):

Consider file:

```
apple
banana
bar TEST qux
TEST foo
baz TEST 
TEST
TEST
```

Insert a line before the first occurrence of a line consisting solely of the string 'TEST':

```
sed '0,/^TEST$/s//INSERTED LINE\n&/' <file
```

Result:

```
apple
banana
bar TEST qux
TEST foo
baz TEST
INSERTED LINE
TEST
TEST
```

`0,/^TEST$` is an [address range](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Range-Addresses.html). This range begins at the first line of input and extends until a line beginning and ending with `TEST` is reached. The use of a range restricts the region of applicability of the following command, a substitution command in our case.

A note about the meaning of `//`:

> The empty regular expression ‘//’ repeats the last regular expression match
> – https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regexp-Addresses.html

A note about the meaning of the ampersand, `&`, used in the replacement portion of the `s` command:

> the replacement can contain unescaped & characters which reference the whole matched portion of the pattern space
> – https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html

For completeness, here's three additional cases to consider...

Insert a line before the first occurrence of a line containing 'TEST':

```
sed '0,/.*TEST/s//INSERTED LINE\n&/' <file
```

Insert a line before the first occurrence of a line beginning with 'TEST':

```
sed '0,/^TEST/s//INSERTED LINE\n&/' <file
```

Insert a line before the first occurrence of a line ending with 'TEST':

```
sed '0,/.*TEST$/s//INSERTED LINE\n&/' <file
```