# Append line after last match with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Let's assume I have the following input.

```
Header
thing0 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
thing2 some info
thing2 some info
thing3 some info
```

Now, I want to be able to append "foo" on the last successful match of "thing4" like this.

```
Header
thing0 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
foo
thing2 some info
thing2 some info
thing3 some info
```

The order is not necessarily  guaranteed, but the sequential numbering in this example is just to show that there is a searchable keyword before certain lines of text and that they are are **usually** grouped together on input, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Good question, but it's better to mention your platform when it comes to `sed` and `awk` questions, because the _GNU_ implementations of these utilities have many more features that won't work on non-Linux platforms (by default); case in point: your own answer requires the _GNU_ utilities. Also, please avoid vague phrases such as "_generally_ grouped together", because it makes it unclear whether the grouping can be _relied_ upon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using single awk you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ if (/thing4/) p=NR; next} 1; FNR==p{ print "foo" }' file file

Header
thing0 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
foo
thing2 some info
thing2 some info
thing3 some info
```

---

**Earlier Solution:** You can use `tac + awk + tac`:

```
tac file | awk '!p && /thing4/{print "foo"; p=1} 1' | tac
```

Comment: If the input is guaranteed to be sorted, you may be able to do this without `tac`.

Comment: Yes but OP didn't mention that input is sorted

Comment: Correct I did not specify. I should have mentioned that! The order is not guaranteed and @anubhava assumed correctly.  However, this only works if those lines have no text after them. Let me expand on the question.

Comment: ++ for the POSIX-compliant `awk` command at the core, but note that `tac` is a utility exclusive to _GNU_;  on BSD/OSX platforms, you can use `tail -r`; POSIX stipulates neither.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 for your comment about `tac`. I have provided an awk only solution.

Comment: Appreciated. Yours is now the only POSIX-compliant solution that doesn't rely on all matches being grouped together.

Comment: @anubhava Why do you have to put in the file name twice with your awk answer? I thought it was not working when I typed awk only once.

Comment: Because that awk command is working on 2 files. It processes same file twice so we need to input `file` twice in argument list.

Comment: It should be noted, this doesn't actually change the file but prints the modified contents to stdout. The file can be changed in place with GNU awk: `gawk -i inplace 'FNR==NR{ if (/thing4/) p=NR; next} 1; FNR==p{ print "foo" }' file file`

Comment: If you require idempotency: `grep -Fxq 'foo' file || awk 'FNR==NR{ if (/thing4/) p=NR; next} 1; FNR==p{ print "foo" }' file file` (perhaps there's a way to do with this awk alone?)

Comment: The awk command did not work for me.

Comment: @RonJohn: `did not work for me` cannot help anyone. I suggest you post a new question with details and we'll look into that.

Answer (score 8):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/.*thing4[^\n]*/&\nfoo/' file
```

Slurp the file into memory and use the greed of the regexp to place the required string after the last occurrence of the required pattern.

A more efficient (uses minimum memory) but harder to understand is:

```
sed '/thing4[^\n]*/,$!b;//{x;//p;g};//!H;$!d;x;s//&\nfoo/' file
```

The explanation is left to the reader to puzzle over.

Comment: Hello, I know it's bit late but How do I insert variable instead of `foo`? I tried `sed '/thing4[^\n]*/,$!b;//{x;//p;g};//!H;$!d;x;s//&\n'"${foo}"'/' file` but it doesn't work as my variable contains `/` in it. Any suggestions how can I get pas it?

Comment: @Some53 make a new variable which has each `/` prefixed by \. But remember `/` may not be the only such character which needs a prefix in the original variable e.g. `.`,`*`,`^`,`$`,`[`,`]`,`&` and \. Or change the substitution delimiter to say `#`.

Answer (score 8):

```
sed -e "$(grep -n 'thing4' file |tail -1|cut -f1 -d':')a foo" file
```

Use the shell and grep to obtain the last line number that contains the pattern, then use that number as the address for the sed append command.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I found it
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386483/command-to-insert-lines-before-first-match) on the stack. Supplemented with @anubhava 's solution which made use of `tac` to flip append then flip again creating the illusion of appending on the last occurrence. Thanks for the help.

`tac | sed '0,/thing4/s/thing4/foo\n&/' | tac`

Comment: This is very similar but not really better than my suggested awk based solution because it doesn't work with non-gnu sed

Comment: Two `tac`s are expensive here. You can do it without them using either `sed` or `awk`

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$"}
        {$0=gensub(/(.*thing4[^\n]*\n)/,"\\1foo\n","1",$0);printf "%s",$0}' file
```

**Sample input**

```
Header
thing0 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
thing2 some info
thing2 some info
thing3 some info
```

**Sample Output**

```
Header
thing0 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
thing4 some info
foo
thing2 some info
thing2 some info
thing3 some info
```

---

**What happens here**

1. We set the Record Separator RS to null ie `^$`, we treat the entire file as one record.
2. `.*thing4[^\n]*\n` in gensub matches anything till the last line which contain `thing4`.
3. gensub allows to reuse the first matched pattern by a special adjustment `\1`. Since the replacement is a string, we need to add an extra `\` so the whole replacement became `\\1foo\n`. The `\n` is indeed an escape sequence, so we dont' need to put two backward slashed before `n`.

---

**Notes**

1. Solution is gnu-awk specific, but could be easilty tweaked for other versions as well.
2. Since the whole file should be read to the memory, this solution best suits small files, still nbd with files spanning a few megabytes.

Comment: ++; please mention that the solution is _GNU_ `awk`-specific; also, it's worth mentioning that the _entire file is read into memory as a whole_, making this solution suitable only for smaller files; it's better to replace `"g"` with `"1"` (or even `""`) so as not to mistakenly suggest that _multiple_ replacements take place.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear if the lines are always grouped by keyword. If so, then this single `awk` approach should work too:

```
awk -v s=thing3 -v t=foo 'END{if(f) print t} {if($0~s)f=1; else if(f) {print t; f=0}}1' file
```

or:

```
awk -v s=thing0 -v t=foo 'END{if(f)print t} {f=$0~s} f,!f{if(!f)print t}1' file
```

Comment: This is nice trick but will only work if searched pattern `thing4` is on consecutive lines.

Comment: Hi anubhava, yes that is what I mean with "grouped by keyword". Both the sample and the text suggest that may be the case (the text is a bit ambiguous to me)..