# Using AWK found construct in for loop

Tags: shell, awk

I've found this useful asnswer on SO to a problem I'm having (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30387380)

However I cannot figure out how to use the construct within a for loop.

The below is my last attempt

```
awk '
BEGIN{split(ENVIRON["LABELS"], label)}
{
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                !found && /label[i]/ { print "# "label[i];found=1} 1
}'  >> "${TMPFIL}"
```

But that fails with:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 5
 context is
                                !found && /label[i]/ >>>  { <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 5
```

***EDIT TO ADD DETAIL....***

Further to answer from @Inian which needs further refining, here's a bit of further background to help.

I have a list of readings (in a text file) :

```
Foo{foober="x"} 5
Foo{foober="x"} 5
Bar{barfoo="y"} 0
Bar{barfoo"y"} 0
```

So, given something like :

```
LABELS=' 
Foo
Bar' \
awk '
BEGIN{split(ENVIRON["LABELS"], label)}
{
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                !found && /label[i]/ { print "# "label[i];found=1} 1
}'  >> "${TMPFIL}"
```

The expected output looks  like :

```
# Foo
Foo{foober="x"} 5
Foo{foober="x"} 5
# Bar
Bar{barfoo="y"} 0
Bar{barfoo"y"} 0
```

Comment: What is the exact value of `LABELS`? What you have shown seems to be a multi line string. But `split()` works on a single line input delimited by space

Comment: What is your input file?

Comment: @Inian `LABELS` is indeed a multi line string.  But I am open to ideas for better alternatives.  See this question for further backgroud as to where `LABELS` came from : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542983/mapping-readings-with-labels  (and using multi-line string does not seem to affect the output on this one ether ?)

Comment: The input is a `mktemp` plaintext file which holds the output from higher up in my script which creates the main output in the `Foo{foober="x"} 5` style (using awk  loop `print label[I]"{foo=\""nei"\",bar=\""xid"\"}", $i`)  and then pipes it into `sort -d` in preparation for this grouping phase I am working on.

Comment: To get the output you posted from the input you posted is just `awk -F'{' '$1!=p{print "#", $1; p=$1} 1' file` so what's the point of your `LABELS` variable?

Comment: @EdMorton The point of the `LABELS` variable ?  (a) You have to tell `awk` what the groups are, don't you ?  (e.g. group `Foo` and group `Bar`) So it knows where to put the headers ?  (b) The group name forms part of the header (i.e. `# Foo` for `Foo` and `#Bar for Bar`.   If you know of a cleaner/better way to do it, I'm all ears !

Comment: a) No, you don't, awk can just read them from the input file. b) But those group names Foo and Bar are already present in the input. Just run the script in my comment and it'll produce the output you said you want from the input you provided without any reference to a LABELS variable. If that's not all you need then update your question to provide a better example that truly demonstrates your needs and in particular shows why a LABELS variable is necessary.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, I bow to your vastly superior `awk` knowledge !  Copy paste that awk one-liner into an answer and the green tick has your name on it. ;-)

Comment: @LittleCode a version of that is already present at the top of [@RavinderSingh13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58061598/1745001) so just accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** As per OP's ask adding following code now.

```
awk -F"{" 'old!=$1{print "# "$1} {old=$1;print}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following. Considering that you want output as per `$1`'s count where delimiter is space(by default in `awk` it is space)

```
awk '!a[$1]++{print "# header_group_"++count} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

In case you want to look for string before `{` then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="{"} !a[$1]++{print "# header_group_"++count} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this awk script:

```
awk -F'{' '$1!=old{print "# header_group_" ++c}{old=$1}1' file
```

This relies on the field separator `{` such that the first field is the key to group lines together.

When the first field is different from the previous, the header line is printed.

Comment: I apologise, my example was confusing.  I have updated the example in the original question to clarify `LABELS` defines the output, not an incrementing integer. Sorry about that.